# Spectrally flat binary sequence

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm trying to construct a binary sequence of length $2^n$. This sequence will be converted to a square signal of $\pm 1$, where 0 produces $-1$ and 1 produces $1$. I want the resultant signal to be as spectrally flat as possible, minimizing the $L^2$ norm of the continuous Fourier transform. Is there a reason to believe that this problem is hard, such as by equivalence to a known mathematical problem like subset sum, or is there a solution I'm overlooking?

Things I've checked are [Raskar's sequence](https://web.media.mit.edu/%7Eraskar/deblur/), which uses exhaustive search, URA/MURA, and [Levin 2007](https://doi.org/10.1145%2F1276377.1276464). The best method I've considered is genetic optimization, but I'd prefer an optimal solution over a searched one.

The motivation is that I have a reverb with Dirac delta spikes in pre-defined locations, and must choose a sign $\pm 1$ for each spike. Setting all signs to $-1$ produces a pitch determined by the locations, and setting signs randomly eliminates the pitch. This doesn't quite match the problem statement given above, but I think a solution for the above will lead to a solution for this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence

Comment: @datageist That seems to be no better than white noise (which is the random choices I made). In Page 8 of https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1509/1509.01220.pdf, white noise is graphed; its performance is worse than Raskar's sequence.

Comment: So are you trying to do audio reconstruction of some kind?

Comment: I am building the reverb myself, so I control the reverb's coefficients and topology.

Comment: I didn't read the whole paper, but they seem to be evaluating white noise in the context of image reconstruction. In what way does that metric inform what you want to accomplish with reverb?

Comment: Good question; the answer will be a bit technical. The pre-defined locations of the Dirac delta spikes specify the first tap of IIR feedback comb filters. In my topology, these first taps create discrete echoes separated from the rest of the reverb response, and these first taps are heard as a single unit. So it makes sense to optimize their response independently. It happens that the math of the binary sequences here also matches the math of shutter design, even though they are different fields.

Comment: As for image reconstruction, the rest of that paper has additional constraints, and their results are not relevant because their conditions are different. It's only that single comparison on Page 8 which pertains to the topic here. (For example, it is not possible for me to select the best of 3 sequences, like they do.)

Comment: Are you trying to reconstruct the geometry of the room from the early reflections?

Comment: No, I'm not doing any kind of reconstruction. I'm building a reverb in a vacuum. It's only the math of this specific feature (flatness of the Fourier transform of a binary sequence) which coincidentally matches the math of what flutter shutter on-off sequences are trying to do. The subjects are very different, but arrive at the same spot.

Comment: In Raskar's paper, he's interested in the condition number of the smearing matrix related to the sequence as well as its spectral flatness. Does the condition number of the smearing matrix matter for your purposes? Or just the spectral flatness?

Comment: I only care about spectral flatness for my application.

Comment: To be specially flat you would use a series of impulses; rectangular pulses with pseudo random noise pattern will have a Sinc shape in frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Golay Complementary Sequences are spectrally flat.  See [https://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/~kp/golaysurvey.pdf](https://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/%7Ekp/golaysurvey.pdf)  or
[https://www.sfu.ca/~jed/Papers/Davis%20Jedwab.%20Golay%20Reed-Muller.%201999.pdf](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Ejed/Papers/Davis%20Jedwab.%20Golay%20Reed-Muller.%201999.pdf)

The DTFT magnitude spectrums of Golay complementary sequences are flat, the maximum to mean value squared magnitude ratios are upper bounded by $2$ $\left( 3 dB \right)$, for any length $2^{n}$. The construction is easy.

Starting from two sequences $A_{1} = \left[ 1 ~ 1 \right]$, $B_{1} = \left[ 1 ~ -1 \right]$.  Let $A_{2} = \left[ A_{1}, B_{1} \right] = \left[ 1 ~ 1 ~ 1 ~ -1 \right]$, $B_{2} = \left[ A_{1}, -B_{1} \right] = \left[ 1 ~ 1  ~ -1 ~ 1 \right]$.  Continue to get longer length $2^{n}$ sequences:

$A_{n} = \left[ A_{n-1}, B_{n-1} \right]$, $B_{n} = \left[ A_{n-1}, -B_{n-1} \right]$. Use either $A_{n}$ or $B_{n}$.

There are ways to construct $0.5 \left( n! \right) 2^{\left( n + 1 \right)}$ different length $2^{n}$, {1, -1}-valued Golay complementary sequences (see Davis and Jedwab's paper), but the spectrally flat property is valid for all Golay complementary sequences, so they are all equally good.